# Connecting third party Facebook page via messenger api

Tags: facebook, oauth, messenger

I have an application that uses the Facebook messenger api to send and receive messages through a Facebook page. This works great. Now I need to be able to have a user in my application link their page so that messages sent to their page will send webhooks to our endpoint, and also give us the ability to send messages through that page using an auth_token.

**Is there any way to do this via api, or will each user have to manually create a Facebook app, generate an auth_token for their page, and set the webhooks url to our endpoint?** I've read about messenger [account linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/account-linking) but I don't think it's quite what I need, as I'm not just looking to request additional profile information.

Answer (score 0):

After looking a bit deeper, I found that in order to do this you must perform an OAuth flow to get an auth_token for the *user*, then use the graph api to get an auth_token for the desired user's page. Then with the page auth_token you can make a POST request to the [subscribed_apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps) endpoint, which will then add the page to the app's webhook events.